# First line of text file not read in shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Okay so Ive compile this code to read a text file however it succesfully finds the sum of every column needed except from the first line! Hence gives me the wrong summation which excludes the value on the first line it reads in. It sets value: $line = ddsdfj:jdskf:1:fjf but never extracts the 1 from the first line. Any clues would be appreciated.

```
FILE=$1
while read line
do
 awk -F: '{summation += $3;}END{print summation;}'
done < $FILE
```

Comment: How is that even working? you haven't passed anything to awk to read ??

Comment: i'll call it through bash --> ./filename.sh some.txt

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop is completely superfluous.  It looks like what you want is

```
awk -F: '{s+=$3}END{print s}' "$1"
```

quite simply.

The code you had would read the first line with `read`, then the other lines as standard input to `awk`; hence, the behavior you were observing.  Something like

```
while read line; do
    awk -F: '{s+=$3}END{print s}' <<<"$line"
done <"$1"
```

would have actually used the value from `line` for something, but of course, that would just extract the third field from each line individually, not performed any actual addition of values from different lines.